# Double slit wavefunction doesn't converge

Tags: electromagnetic-radiation, wavefunction, renormalization, double-slit-experiment

I'm trying to plot the exact solution to wavefunction of the double slit experiment.

I'm assuming sphere waves radiating with 1/r at each point. In other words, here's **the exact solution** I'm solving for, numerically:
$\psi(x',z)= \int_{\text{(-d/2-g to -d/2) and (d/2 to d/2+g)}} \dfrac{e^{i k r(x,x',z)}}{r(x,x',z)}dx $

Where of course $r(x,x',z)=((x-x')^2+z^2)^{.5}$

d=distance between slits, g = width of each slit, z = how far slits are from the screen, all in meters. Just know z is much greater than d and g. x= position on slits, x' = position on screen.

And here's the plot of $|\psi(x',z=100)|^2$ I'm getting:

[image: my exact numerical solution]

This looks slightly different from when you plot the Fraunhoffer diffraction pattern (which is $[\text{sinc}(k g x/2z) \cos(k d x / 2z)]^2$ if you're curious), and I trust this more because it doesn't have any approximations.

The only problem is, if I numerically integrate x' from, say 300 to 10000, or to 1000000, or to 100000000000000, I can see that the integral gets bigger and bigger by that factor. And Mathematica is telling me the integral can't be computed. Which means the solution is not normalizable.

Here's my code:

```
d = 2.17
g = .6
k = 9.6
z = 100

(* 1/r e^{I k r}*)
(* implemented as 1/r (F = Cos | Sin)(k r)   *)
F0[x2_, z_, A_, B_, F_] := NIntegrate[((x2 - x0)^2 + z^2)^-.5 F[k ((x2 - x0)^2 + z^2)^.5], {x0, A, B}]

(* real part of the integral *)
R11[x2_, z_] := F0[x2, z, -d/2 - g, -d/2, Cos] + F0[x2, z, d/2, d/2 + g, Cos]
(* imaginary part of the integral *)
I11[x2_, z_] := F0[x2, z, -d/2 - g, -d/2, Sin] + F0[x2, z, d/2, d/2 + g, Sin]


(* psi squared *)
G[x2_, z_] := R11[x2, z]^2 + I11[x2, z]^2

(* normalizing factor (I'm not sure why this is needed... shouldn't it be normalized?) *)
a1 = NIntegrate[G[x3, z], {x3, -2 z, 2 z}]

(* plot the normalized probability distribution *)
GN[x2_, z_] := G[x2, z]/a1;
Plot[GN[x, z], {x, -2 z, 2 z}, PlotRange -> All, 
 PlotLabel -> "Numerical soluton to integral of 1/r e^ikr dx"]


a2 = NIntegrate[G[x, z], {x, 300, 10000000000}]
```

I'm confused how I'm getting a non-normalizable solution, when when the 1/r is specifically there to serve as a normalizing factor. What am I missing?

Comment: What is the parameter that you are changing to 1000000? We also cannot know if you have a mistake in the code implementation.

Comment: The parameter is the thing I'm plotting over. $x'$. I added my code.

Comment: It seems to be numerical difficulties. Numerical integrals of oscillating functions like that tends to go haywire. Note that you only have conditional convergence, making it easy to diverge. I mean, integrating |1/r| gives a ln r, then you squared this and integrated, so it is not surprising for numerical difficulties to cause trouble.

Comment: Thanks for your response. But I'm not integrating 1/r, I'm integrating 1/r squared!

Comment: No, you are not. Inside R11 and I11 you are integrating cos(kr)/r and sin(kr)/r, and if we ignore the trigo, then you are integrating 1/r. Then you squared them and added, before doing one more integral. The original integrals are conditionally convergent, so numerical difficulties in the oscillating trigo integrals is more than likely to cause it to diverge.

Comment: So you think it's just due to numerical error, and it really does converge? I'm having trouble imagining how numerical error could give rise to this. I zoomed in and it doesn't look oscillatory at all, it looks like 1/x' as x' gets big.

Comment: I get $0.0000439548$ for the integral from $300$ to $10000000000$. What are you getting? Maybe it's a bug in Mathematica.

Comment: Mmm... It's not the exact solution. That involves the Rayleigh-Sommerfeld diffraction integral which has extra factors.

Answer (score 1):

Looking at your code, there are a few things that could be causing the problem. I'll break it down for you:

Normalization Factor: You mentioned that you're not sure why the normalization factor is necessary. In quantum mechanics, we need to normalize the wavefunction to ensure the probability of finding the particle in any state is 1. To calculate a suitable normalization factor, you can integrate the squared magnitude of the wavefunction over the entire range of x from -2z to 2z. This factor can be obtained by using the following line of code:

```
a1 = NIntegrate[GN[x, z], {x, -2 z, 2 z}]^2
```

Integration Range: It seems you're facing convergence issues when integrating the wavefunction over larger x' ranges. That's expected because the 1/r term in your equation can lead to divergence as the distance from the source increases. This divergence happens because the assumption of spherical wave propagation becomes less accurate the farther you go from the source. To tackle this, you might need to use a better approximation or adjust the numerical integration method.

Numerical Integration: The numerical integration method you're using, NIntegrate, might struggle with the complex integrand and the large integration range. It's worth trying different integration methods like Monte Carlo or adaptive quadrature techniques to improve convergence and accuracy. Additionally, increasing the working precision of NIntegrate could help resolve the convergence issue.

Analytical Approach: While numerical methods are handy, an analytical solution might shed light on the behavior of the wavefunction in the double slit experiment. One option is to solve the problem using a simplified model, like the Fraunhofer diffraction pattern you mentioned. Although this model involves approximations, it can still give a good estimate in many practical cases. Comparing your numerical results to the analytical Fraunhofer diffraction pattern can help validate your calculations.

To sum it up, here's what you can do to address the non-normalizable solution and convergence issues in your double slit wavefunction calculation:

Calculate an appropriate normalization factor a1 by integrating the squared magnitude of the wavefunction over the entire range of x from -2z to 2z:

```
a1 = NIntegrate[GN[x, z], {x, -2 z, 2 z}]^2
```

Divide the original wavefunction G[x2, z] by the normalization factor a1 to obtain the normalized wavefunction:

```
GN[x2_, z_] := G[x2, z] / a1
```

Experiment with alternative numerical integration methods or increase the working precision to improve convergence and accuracy.Then I'd recommend comparing your numerical results with analytical approximations, such as the Fraunhofer diffraction pattern, to validate your calculations, which is described by the following equation:

```
[sinc(kgx/2z)cos(kdx/2z)]^2
```

I hope with the provided steps you'll gain a better understanding of the wavefunction in the double slit experiment.

Good luck, and don't hesitate to ask if you have any further questions!